# Apache RewriteRule to subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all requests to a folder to a subfolder. An example of this is what openbay has: https://github.com/isohuntto/openbay/blob/master/.htaccess

My folder looks like this:

```
Main/
└── src
    ├── app
    └── public
        ├── index.php
```

What I want to do is when you go to the Main folder, you go to the index.php found in the public folder and the same with other files.

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ src/public/$1
```

Which results in an Internal Server Error (500) and in the apache log it will say:

```
[Fri Dec 19 22:53:26.447255 2014] [core:error] [pid 3497] [client 127.0.0.1:37913] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

What can I do to make it behave like I want it to?

Comment: If there's a misconfiguration, a hacker could get the sourcecode of your website. That's why you put almost everything outside the public folder and `index.php` should include a certain bootstrap which is outside the public folder. So I would not support/suggest what you're trying to do.

Comment: @HamZa The public folder won't contain any source code. That goes into app.

Comment: this config doesn't work since you're redirecting EVERYTHING ((.*)$) to src/public, which is then redirected to /src/public, etc...

Comment: @patrick That's what I'm struggeling with, I can't figure out how to get it to work the way I want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid infinite looping by adding `RewriteCond` that will skip rewrite for a valid file or directory. Replace your rule by this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ src/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ src/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Great! That works, thanks. Now how would I go about making it also automatically go to the index.php? E.g going to Main goes to public/index.php without having to type Main/index.php

Comment: If you visit `example.com/` it will automatically load `example.com/src/public/`. If you visit `example.com/foobar` it will automatically load `example.com/src/public/foobar`.

Comment: Hmm weird, not for me. Going to `example.com/` shows the files and folders of Main, while going to `example.com/src/public/` does show the index properly.

Comment: _“Going to example.com/ shows the files and folders of Main”_ – I think that happens because `/` points to an existing directory (`Main/`) already, so the RewriteCond checking for that leads no rewriting being done at all …